# Passing Cache Image Via Segue to DetailViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uistoryboardsegue

I am using data task to display textual data from external server via JSON File. which is working pretty fine 
and I am using AFNetworking's file `#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"` to download image from above extracted data in Tableview's Cell declaration it also working pretty fine. 
But when selecting a row to pass selected rows Image via Segue to another view controller it giving error,

Here is my code for Tableview's cell which is pretty fine & Displaying textual & Image data

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"maincell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Categories * CategoryObject;
    CategoryObject = [categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = CategoryObject.categoryTitle;

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    // Configure the cell Image...

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:CategoryObject.categoryImage];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    UIImage *placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"];
    __weak UITableViewCell *weakCell = cell;
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:placeholderImage success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
        weakCell.imageView.image = image;
        [weakCell setNeedsLayout];
    } failure:nil];

    return cell;   
}
```

Now take a look at Segue code which giving error

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showAnotherView"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
       DetailImageViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.imageName = [ UIImageView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row.image];

    }
}
```

my code giving error

> no known class method for selector `objectAtIndex:`

in last line of the code

```
destViewController.imageName = [ UIImageView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row.image];
```

The thing I want to accomplish is to resolve this error and to pass above cached image which is downloaded via AFNetworking and to pass that image in segue to display in next view controller. could anyone help me out?

Comment: 'objectAtIndex' works on arrays.  'UIImageView' isn't an array.  'indexPath.row' is a number.  Numbers don't have an 'image' property.  In other words, that line of code is so wrong that I can't guess what value it's supposed to be accessing.

Comment: @philiip Mills,  yes you are right, Hence I needs to know which value should we pass here in this line of code whereas I extracted images via AFNetworking code, in above. where I declared in comments `// Configure the cell Image...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, it seems like you are accessing `objectAtIndex:` method on `UIImageView` which don't have the method unless you have category class extending `UIImageView`. If you are going to handle the raw selection, it should be something like this,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showAnotherView"]) 
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        UITableViewCell * cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        DetailImageViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.imageName = Cell.imageView.image;

    }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: can't get cleared, would you please resolve the issue with your suggested code?

Comment: This time your Code fits Perfectly, yet there is a minor mistake for which compiler given me hint to change it. that is at the last line's `Cell.imageView.image;`  where as corrected is `cell.imageView.image;`  I mean there's a small `c` instead of capital `c`  of `cell`.
Thanks a lot, you've resolved a major issue of my app.